# Every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point iff every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let X be a metric space. Show that the following two statements are equivalent: $(i)$ Every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point; $(ii)$ Every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

I would appreciate if anyone could verify whether my proof of the statement above is correct.

My attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point. Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence in $X$. $\{a_n\}$ is an infinite subset of $X$, so $\{a_n\}$ has a limit point. Let $x$ be a limit point of $\{a_n\}$. Then every neighborhood of $x$ contains some term in $\{a_n\}$. Choose $a_{n_k}\in\{a_n\}$ so that $a_{n_k}\in N_{\frac{1}{k}}(x)\setminus N_{\frac{1}{k+1}}(x)$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists some $K>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ so that for all $k\geq K$, $d(a_{n_k}, x)<\frac{1}{K}<\varepsilon.$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence. Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $X$. Let $b_n$ be a sequence in $X$. Then $b_n$ has a convergent subsequence $b_{n_k}$ that converges to $b$. Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Then there exists an $N$ so that for all $n_k\geq N, d(b_{n_k}, b)<\varepsilon \implies b_{n_k}\in N_\varepsilon(b)$ for all $n_k\geq N \implies b$ is a limit point of $A.$

Comment: In the $\impliedby$ direction, when you say "Let $b_n$ be a sequence in $X$", did you mean $A$ instead?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Could you please specify precisely what definition of "limit point" you're using? I would answer differently depending on how it's worded.

Comment: $x$ is a limit point of $E$ if for all $r>0,$ there exists some $p\in E$ such that $0<d(x,p)<r.$

Comment: "Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $X$. Then $\{a_n \}$ is an infinite subset of $X$" : this statement is *not* true, for example if $a_n$ contains only finitely many distinct terms, like $1,2,1,2,1,2,...$.  So you need to handle this case separately.

Comment: Dually to астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг's concern, you need to deal with the possibility $b_{n_k}$ is eventually constant. In particular, assume $b_n$ is an **injective** sequence in $A$ to eliminate such a possibility.

Comment: I think the only other issue that needs to be addressed is that you cannot assume that $N_{1/k}(x) \setminus N_{1/(k+1)}(x)$ contains any sequence points. Instead just choose $a_{n_k} \in N_{1/k}(x) \setminus \{x\}$, and the argument still works.

Comment: Thank you, I was just about to comment that I couldn't assume that statement.

Answer (score 1):

The backwards direction is easy: if $A$ is infinite, there is an injection $f: \Bbb N \to A$ which defines a sequence $f(n)=a_n$ in $A$. If $b$ is the limit of a convergent subsequence of $(a_n)$, it's a limit point of $A$, this is clear as all terms $A_n$ are distinct.

The forwards case needs a case distinction: If $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A$, then $S=\{a_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ can be finite or infinite. If it is finite, some term occurs infinitely often and we have a convergent (even constant) subsequence , otehrwise $S$ is infinite and has a limit point $b$. Then pick $a_{n_k} \in S$ with increasing indices $n_k$ in $B(b, \frac{1}{k})$ which can be done as every neighbourhood of $b$ contains infinitely many (!) terms of $S$. This then defines the required subsequence. (This works in any first countable $T_1$ space, really). You cannot always garantuee points in the difference of the balls as you claim, and you don't need to either.